# fabric-sdk-java invoke chaincode doesn't work

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I use fabric-sdk-java to query and invoke chaincode which start by byfn fabric. When I query a value, the `a` is 90, and I invoke `a,b,10`. Then the `a` value should be 80,right? But after I invoke chaincode, I query the `a` value is still 90. So I want to ask way? and how can I solve it?

Below is my code :

```
public class FabricJavaSdkSample {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        final CryptoSuite crypto = CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite();

        System.out.println("Creating client");
        final HFClient client = HFClient.createNewInstance();
        client.setCryptoSuite(crypto);


        System.out.println("Loading org1 User1 from disk");

        final String privateKeyFileName = "/Users/zhangyulong/Documents/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/c050bce32a20c8c3bda5b7a9320c6e6f043fe2ff22af645b12844a46f7e97f0c_sk";

        final String certificateFileName = "/Users/zhangyulong/Documents/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem";
        final File privateKeyFile = new File(privateKeyFileName);
        final File certificateFile = new File(certificateFileName);
        final User User1 = Utils.getUser("PeerAdmin", "Org1MSP", privateKeyFile, certificateFile);
        client.setUserContext(User1);

        // Accessing channel, should already exist
        System.out.println("Accessing channel");
        Channel myChannel = client.newChannel("mychannel");

        System.out.println("Setting channel configuration");
        final List<Peer> peers = new LinkedList<>();
        Properties peerProperties = new Properties();

        peerProperties.setProperty("pemFile",
                "/Users/zhangyulong/Documents/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt");

        peerProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "peer0.org1.example.com");
        peerProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
        peerProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
        peerProperties.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true"); // testing // // PRODUCTION!
        peerProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 9000000);
        peers.add(client.newPeer("peer0.org1.example.com", "grpcs://localhost:7051", peerProperties));

        myChannel.addPeer(peers.get(0), createPeerOptions().setPeerRoles(EnumSet.of(PeerRole.ENDORSING_PEER,
                PeerRole.LEDGER_QUERY, PeerRole.CHAINCODE_QUERY, PeerRole.EVENT_SOURCE)));

        Properties ordererProperties = new Properties();
        ordererProperties.setProperty("pemFile",
                "/Users/zhangyulong/Documents/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt");
        ordererProperties.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true");
        ordererProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "orderer.example.com");
        ordererProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
        ordererProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
        ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTime", new Object[] { 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES });
        ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTimeout", new Object[] { 8L, TimeUnit.SECONDS });
        myChannel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpcs://localhost:7050", ordererProperties));

        myChannel.initialize();

        // Creating proposal for query
        System.out.println("Creating proposal for query(a)");
        final QueryByChaincodeRequest queryAProposalRequest = client.newQueryProposalRequest();
        final ChaincodeID queryChaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("mycc").setVersion("1.0").build();
        queryAProposalRequest.setChaincodeID(queryChaincodeID);
        queryAProposalRequest.setFcn("query");
        // queryAProposalRequest.setFcn("queryAllCars");
        queryAProposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
        queryAProposalRequest.setArgs(new String[] { "a" });
        int blocksize = (int) myChannel.queryBlockchainInfo().getHeight();
        System.out.println("NO of Blocks: " + blocksize);
        // Send proposal and wait for responses
        System.out.println("Sending proposal for query");
        final Collection<ProposalResponse> queryAResponses = myChannel.queryByChaincode(queryAProposalRequest,
                myChannel.getPeers());

        for (ProposalResponse resp : queryAResponses) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Response from peer " + resp.getPeer().getName() + " is " + resp.getProposalResponse().getResponse()
                            + resp.getProposalResponse().getResponse().getPayload().toStringUtf8());
        }

        // Creating proposal for query
        System.out.println("Creating proposal for invoke(a,b,10)");

        final TransactionProposalRequest invokeProposalRequest = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();
        invokeProposalRequest.setChaincodeID(queryChaincodeID);
        invokeProposalRequest.setFcn("invoke");
        invokeProposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
        invokeProposalRequest.setArgs(new String[] { "a", "b", "10" });

        final Collection<ProposalResponse> queryBResponses = myChannel.sendTransactionProposal(invokeProposalRequest,
                myChannel.getPeers());
        for (ProposalResponse resp : queryBResponses) {
            System.out.println("Response from peer " + resp.getPeer().getName() + " is"
                    + resp.getProposalResponse().getResponse());
        }
```

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: I still have this question

Comment: I have figured this out. Apparently, sdk doesn't send the transactions to the orders by default. You have to do that explicitly by calling "sendTransaction" method with responses retrieved from "sendTransactionProposal"

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being sent to the orderer. Look at the integration test supplied to you by the SDK as the README suggests.  It shows a blance transfer transaction with queries that test the changes and much more.

Comment: where is the website?can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

for write a new block in a fabric network you will do 3 step:

1. send a transaction proposal request to the peers (they simulate the transaction in this phase);
2. collect the proposal responses from all peers;

if all responses are congruent you can do the following step:

3. send the transaction to all peers.

while, for query you need to do only the step 1.

---

So, in your code you do only the step 1. To complete you need to add the following code:

```
// STEP 1
final Collection<ProposalResponse> queryBResponses = myChannel.sendTransactionProposal(invokeProposalRequest,
                myChannel.getPeers());
        for (ProposalResponse resp : queryBResponses) {
            System.out.println("Response from peer " + resp.getPeer().getName() + " is"
                    + resp.getProposalResponse().getResponse());
        }


// STEP 2
Collection<ProposalResponse> successful = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<ProposalResponse> failed = new ArrayList<>();
for (ProposalResponse response : queryBResponses) {
    if (response.getStatus() == ProposalResponse.Status.SUCCESS) {
        successful.add(response);
    } else {
        failed.add(response);
    }
}

if (failed.size() > 0) throw new BlockChainException("...");
// CHECK CONSISTENCY
Collection<Set<ProposalResponse>> proposalConsistencySets = SDKUtils.getProposalConsistencySets(queryBResponses);
if (proposalConsistencySets.size() != 1) {
    throw new BlockChainException("...");
}
// STEP 3
CompletableFuture<BlockEvent.TransactionEvent> transactionEventCompletableFuture = channel.sendTransaction(successful);
```